# Add article to SQL Server merge replication with partially snapshot initialization

Tags: sql-server, replication, merge-replication

I have a merge replication scenario with one publication and multiple subscriber.

I  have also a two types of tables. First base tables that has the same in all subscriber.  Second, multiple table that have same structure in all subscriber but with different data (data replicate with filter row condition).

I want to add add few new subscriber to this scenario. but when I add a new table in my article SQL Server need to reinitialize all subscriber. I do not to initialize subscriber automatically because of large amount of data and latency between links.

My question is how can I add a new subscriber without reinitializtion or with manually initialization?

Comment: Sample data and a real example would help explain what you want to do.

Comment: i want to a new articles with mini-snapshot rather than full snapshot in merge replication.